# What is the correct Syntax for ListAdapter with ListFragment Class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm currently converting my app from activities to fragments and i'm struggling to implement ListAdapters.

Below is my code.

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        FindPeopleFragment.this, outboxList,
                        getActivity().R.layout.women_list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_TO ,TAG_DATE,TAG_EMAIL,TAG_SUBJECT},
                        new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.date,R.id.mail,R.id.roundscore });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                    outboxList,R.layout.women_list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_TO ,TAG_DATE,TAG_EMAIL,TAG_SUBJECT},
                        new int[] { R.id.from, R.id.subject, R.id.date,R.id.mail,R.id.roundscore });
```

I believe this may be correct